# Importar stl en blender 2.8

Tags: blender

He instalado la versión 2.8 de Blender y al entrar en importar para importar un archivo `stl`, no veo la opción, no se como se hace. Veo dos opciones.

```
Collada y Alembic
```

Como puedo importar los stl? Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La opción mencionada esta en el menú import.
Indica por favor el binario que haz usado para instalar así como el Sistema Operativo sobre el cual realizaste la instalación. 
En la instalación que hice sobre Fedora 29 se ve de inmediato la opción.

[image: Aquí esta la opción]

Comment: Tengo la versión 2.8 descargada de https://www.blender.org/download/ en un win 64 bits. Las unicas versiones que aparecen son las mencionadas antes.